# Openfaces 3.0 running in WebSphere 7

Tags: jsf-2, websphere-7, openfaces

Has anyone around gotten Openfaces 3.0 to run on WebSphere 7.0?

I keep on getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.application.ResourceWrapper.getRequestPath(ResourceWrapper.java:118)
at org.openfaces.application.OpenFacesResource.getRequestPath(OpenFacesResource.java:36)
at org.openfaces.util.Resources.getInternalURL(Resources.java:133)
at org.openfaces.util.Resources.getUtilJsURL(Resources.java:234)
at org.openfaces.util.UtilPhaseListener.appendHeaderContent(UtilPhaseListener.java:60)
at org.openfaces.application.OpenFacesApplication.headAddedToView(OpenFacesApplication.java:79)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

floshton.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do OpenFaces/Websphere, so I can't go in detail about this, but given the fact that [`ResourceWrapper#getRequestPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceWrapper.html#getRequestPath%28%29) delegates as per its source code the call as follows

```
return getWrapped().getRequestPath();
```

Where [`ResourceWrapper#getWrapped()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceWrapper.html#getWrapped%28%29) is an **abstract** method which is to be implemented properly by the implementor. Given the trace, it's the `org.openfaces.application.OpenFacesResource` which is incorrectly returning `null` on `getWrapped()`.

What the underlying cause is, is unclear since I don't have the hands on OpenFaces source code directly. I'd start by reporting this issue to the OpenFaces guys on their [forum](http://links.teamdev.com/openfaces-forum) and/or [issue tracker](http://requests.openfaces.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: First of all, thanks BalusC four your reply. I've seen you in a number of Stack Overflow posts and I am an avid follower of your blog.

After a lot of research, I found out that OpenFaces 3.0 needs Mojarra 2.0.3 to run effectively, and I was using 2.0.2. So I just replaced the jar files and voila!

I've been reading the Mojarra 2.0.3 Release Notes (http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.0.3/whatsnew.html), but I am frankly not sure about the reason it now does work.

Anyway, thanks a lot.

floshton

Comment: You're welcome. Sicne you already solved the problem by yourself (upgrading to 2.0.3), you're obligated to repost this as an answer and then mark it accepted :)